# Unity - Failed to compile resources while building android 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is what the console says .. I tried to change the sdk build tools and also updated the jdk to 9,1 but nothing worked

```
Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
-bootclasspath "/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar" -d "/Users/mac/Desktop/ReSkiN/Code Source Andriod/ZombieLand_SourceCode/Temp/StagingArea/bin/classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "android/support/v4/R.java" "android/support/v7/cardview/R.java" "com/facebook/R.java" "com/facebook/android/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/base/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/gass/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/tasks/R.java" "com/google/unity/R.java" "com/ponygames/ZombieLand/R.java" "com/unity3d/ads/R.java"
warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: So... have you thought about changing the values that it warns about or suppressing them using the options it mentions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to compile to android (Unity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426770/failed-to-compile-to-android-unity)

Comment: i uploided this code and send it to freelancers to fix , they say there is no wrong with the code it it is sdk or jdk problem !

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because of **(JDK 9)**. You should install the latest version of **(JDK 8)**, that will fix it.

Comment: it was jdk 8 what i installed before , nothing worked

Comment: Have you specified **(JDK 8)** in Unity preferences?

Comment: Could you try entering the following command: `echo $JAVA_HOME` to Terminal, and then please tell me what is the output.

Comment: my mestake shaman , it worked i specifided jdk 8 as default , thankyou man